# Finding the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of a beautiful function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

I have to find the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of the following function

$$y= \frac{x+2}{\sqrt[3]{1-x}}$$

I tried taking the derivative for a couple of times to find some patterns but it didn't help.
I feel like I have to use some formulas for common function's $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative, but in my function-as you can see- there are 2 types of functions so I don't know what i should do. Also I don't know any series yet, I don't know if that was necessary, just in case. Could you please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: All functions are beautiful

Comment: @Snoop sorry :( i didn't mean to upset you, this one is just not really my type

Comment: @Snoop For me, the beauty of any function is not well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{x+2}{\sqrt[3]{1-x}}= \frac{3-(1-x)}{\sqrt[3]{1-x}}= 3(1-x)^{-1/3}-(1-x)^{2/3}$$

so

$$f^{(n)}(x)=3\frac13\frac43\frac73\cdots\frac{3n-2}3(1-x)^{-1/3-n}+\frac23\frac13\frac43\cdots\frac{3n+1}3(1-x)^{2/3-n}.$$

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

Use the Leibnitz formula, which gives the $n^{\text{th}} $ derivative of a product :
$$(f.g)^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom {n}{k} f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}$$

with

$$f(x)=x+2, \;\; f''=f^{(3)}=...=0$$
and
$$g(x)=(1-x)^{-\frac 13}$$

Comment: I was reading in Italian your formula of your answer. https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/formula-di-newton-leibniz_%28altro%29/ ...haha. 19 Scudetto of the Inter Club :-)

Comment: Hello amigo. with Achraf hakimi. forza Inter Pirelli.